# Derive closed form interpretation of negative binomial regression linear term coefficient

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, biostatistics, negative-binomial-distribution, poisson-regression

Consider an experimental setup where any given individual is either exposed or unexposed to some treatment A. Some over-dispersed count variable is measured as the outcome. This can be modelled with a negative binomial regression as follows:

$log\big(E[\text{outcome}|\text{exposed to treatment A}]\big)=\beta_0+\beta_1I(\text{exposed to treatment A})$

The parameters $\beta_0,\beta_1$ have no closed form solution and are solved using some [optimization technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_regression).

However, it is always the case that:

$\beta_1=\log{\frac{\mu(\text{outcome}|\text{exposed to treatment A})}{\mu(\text{outcome}|\text{unexposed to treatment A})}}$

I cannot find any derivation of this result. Any help deriving this mathematically?

Comment: I don't think your last equation is quite correct; are you sure it isn't $\beta_1 = \log (\dots)$?

Comment: Sorry yes, you are right! I will make the edit in the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that, as $I(\text{exposed to treatment A})= 0$ when the individual was not exposed to treatment A and $1$ when they were exposed to A, it follows that:

$$\log\big(E[\text{outcome}|\text{not exposed to A}]\big)=\beta_0$$

and
$$\log\big(E[\text{outcome}|\text{exposed to A}]\big)=\beta_0 + \beta_1$$

so

$$\log\big(E[\text{outcome}|\text{exposed to A}]\big) -\log\big(E[\text{outcome}|\text{not exposed to A}]\big) = \beta_1 $$

and, as $\log a - \log b = \log (a/b)$, we are a single algebraic step from the desired result.